# Unique Key on columns from different tables

Tags: mysql, sql

Is it possible in MySQL create a unique index on two columns from the different table? I have two table - Address (addressID - pk, customerID, code) and Customer (customerID - pk, companyID). PK- primary key. The requirement is a unique pair of code-companyID - unique address code per company. Any suggestion? Can I implement this requirement in DB level or only in beck-end side?

Comment: You can create a foreign key, is that what you mean?

Comment: You are looking to create a one-to-one relationship. You should create a foreign key on `code` to `companyId`, and also add a unique index on `code`.

Comment: An index cannot span tables in mysql.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, indexes cannot span multiple tables. However, your do not seem to grasp the way relationships are implemented in sql, hence the question.

If a customer can have a single address only, then the `address id` should be a field in the `customer` table with a foreign key pointing to the `address` table. In this case you do not need a multi-column unique index.

If a customer can have multiple addresses (and obviously, multiple customers may have the same address), then you have a many-to-many relationship. This is resolved by creating a 3rd table (let's call it `CustomersAddresses`), which will have the `customer id` and `address id` as fields (as a minimum). You define the multi-column unique index over these two fields in this `CustomersAddresses` table, ensuring that address - customer pairs are unique.

The `customer id` and `address id` fields in the `CustomersAddresses` table will be foreign keys pointing to the respective standing tables.